# Using the Past Simple with the "in the last" expression

Tags: past-perfect, past-simple, past-vs-past-perfect

> Almost half  of the people who **bought** a vinyl record **in** **the
>   last 12 months** did so after hearing on a streaming  site

Since the expression "in the last 12 months" includes the current moment of time, could I use the Pesent Perfect for ***"to buy"*** and ***"to do"***?

> Almost half of the people who **have bought** a vinyl record in the
>   last 12 months **have done** so after hearing on a streaming  site or
>   after they have heard it

or

> Almost half of the people who **have bought** a vinyl record in the
>   last 12 months **have done** so after they **have heard** it on a streaming  site

Comment: Yes, you *can* use the present perfect there(**have bought...have done so**), but the hearing itself took place at a discrete moment in the past, and so the simple past **after they heard it** would be more natural, or even a tenseless **after hearing it**.

Comment: Note that *in the last 12 months* modifies only the subordinate relative clause, not the matrix clause.